Throw warning if there is an empty line before \end{proof}
ntheorem does not print the end mark if the last line of the environment is empty:

(from the ntheorem manual).
To avoid the end mark not printing, I want a way to warn me if I accidentally put an empty line before \end{proof}.
As an example, this code should throw a warning:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,standard]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof.

\end{proof} 

\end{document}

But this code should compile without any warnings:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,standard]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof.
\end{proof} 

\end{document}


Package ntheorem Warning: End of proof in vertical mode
(ntheorem)                Check QED marker on input line 15.

Package ntheorem Warning: End of proof in vertical mode
(ntheorem)                Check QED marker on input line 32.

Package ntheorem Warning: End of proof in vertical mode
(ntheorem)                Check QED marker on input line 42.

Package ntheorem Warning: End of proof in vertical mode
(ntheorem)                Check QED marker on input line 54.



is logged from
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,standard]{ntheorem}
\AddToHook{env/proof/end}{%
  \ifvmode
    \PackageWarning{ntheorem}{End of proof in vertical mode\MessageBreak
                             Check QED marker}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof ending in blank line.

\end{proof}

xxxx
  
\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof with no blank line.
%
\end{proof}

xxxx

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof ending with a list.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item aaa
     \item bbb
    \end{itemize}
\end{proof}

xxxx

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof ending with a different list.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item aaa
     \item bbb
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

xxxx

\begin{proof}
    Here is a proof with a nested list then text then a blank line.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item aaa
     \item bbb
     \end{enumerate}
     text with blank line
     
\end{proof}

xxxx

\begin{proof}
    here is a proof with a nested list but no blank.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item aaa
     \item bbb
     \end{enumerate}
     text at end
\end{proof}

\end{document}
  
  
  


Note that ntheorem takes at least two runs to determine where to add the QED mark.  If it ends with blank line the mark may be dropped completely or may be placed incorrectly earlier in the proof. One example here the marker is places at the end of a nested list even though that is not the end of the proof.
The warning added here will warn in those cases but also warns when the proof directly ends in the list and the marker is generally placed correctly automatically. Fixing that would require deeper patching and would probably break something unless done by someone who knows the code better. However the warning may serve as a reminder to check potentially problematic cases.

Thank you! This is great. One thing to note: if the proof ends with an enumerate environment: e.g.
\begin{proof} \begin{enumerate} \item Proof 1 \item Proof 2 \end{enumerate} \end{proof}
then the end mark is still printed (correctly) but the warning is raised

@James see update, I extended the example and left some comments about lists.

That makes sense. I also had a quick look at the ntheorem code and it looks to be difficult to properly patch.
